# Eliminate span line break without moving text to new line

Tags: css

I have this right now:

```css
 #outer-div {
      border: 1px dashed red;
      line-height: 50px;
      width: 350px;
    }
    
    .inner-div {
      border: 1px dashed red;
      float:left;
      height: 50px;
      width:80px;
    }
    #title {
      /*white-space: nowrap;*/
    }
```

```html
  <div id="outer-div">
      <div class="inner-div"></div>
      <div class="inner-div"></div>
      <span id="title">Random long text not to break<span>
    </div>
```

and it looks like:

[image]

and I'd need this:

[image]

Tried solutions from other threads but they not work as this. `white-space: nowrap` moves the entire span to the next line.

Here is a working code: https://codepen.io/neptune01/pen/ppMyEQ

Can this be done using only css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit tricky, but doable using Flexbox (as is almost anything), `text-overflow: ellipsis`, and, yes, `white-space: nowrap` :

Bonus: you don't need `line-height` or `float`.

```css
#outer-div {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.inner-div {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 80px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

#title {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  border: blue dashed 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer-div">
  <div class="inner-div"></div>
  <div class="inner-div"></div>
  <span id="title">Random long text not to break</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the `white-space: nowrap` together with the `text-overflow: ellipsis` and `overflow: hidden`, also the `#title` span needs to be displayed as `block` or you can just use another `div` instead:

```css
#outer-div {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 350px;
}

.inner-div {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  width: 80px;
}

#title {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer-div">
  <div class="inner-div"></div>
  <div class="inner-div"></div>
  <span id="title">Random long text not to break</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign `id` just to your `parent` div and not to other elements present inside.

`white-space:nowrap` makes contents present inside applied div to not `wrap` them `next line`, so you need to add `overflow:hidden` too, which hides content from overflowing outside `.title` or targeted div, thus this hides content and then apply `text-overflow:ellipsis` to get `(...)` in end of overflowed content.

```css
#outer-div {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 350px;
}

.inner-div {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  width: 80px;
}

.title {
  display: block; /*Changed display to block*/
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer-div">
  <div class="inner-div"></div>
  <div class="inner-div"></div>
  <span class="title">Random long text overflows content out of box.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Check this jsFiddle to get same ellipsis styling on other child divs too https://jsfiddle.net/yzahpwez/